# Url Rewrite in IIS get 404

Tags: iis

```
<rule name="List_of_mfrs" enabled="true">
    <match url="/Manufacturers_(\w)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/list_of_mfrs/mfrs.cfm?ot={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When I enter: `http://MyLocalHost/list_of_mfrs/mfrs.cfm?ot=R` It gets 404 error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I got why it happened: because of the character `/` in `@type` and `@url`

Here is the correct text:

```
<rule name="List_of_mfrs" enabled="true">
    <match url="Manufacturers_(\w)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="list_of_mfrs/mfrs.cfm?ot={R:1}" />
</rule>
```