# URL rewrite in IIS 8.5 is not working I'm getting 404 instead

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

Hi I've configured a rewrite rule on my IIS but it seems like it never gets fired I've been working on this for several hours without any luck this is my rule in the **web config** of the appplication:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite frienly url to snapshot" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="/(localhost:2934)\/trabajos\/([\w-]+)\/([\w-|\-]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="\/snapshots/{R:2}.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

my URL is the following:

http://localhost:2934/trabajos/3ba2a9e4/some-cool-title
'

and I want to rewrite as:

http://localhost:2934/snapshots/3ba2a9e4.html

this is the result I get from testing the pattern in the IIS:

[image: tesing URL rewrite iis]

to me seems to be ok

but when testing the URL in the browser, I feel like the rule never gets fired, in fact, I've configured to trace failed request like [this tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and I don't get any error or file in the logs folder.
ex: C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

I'm getting a 404 error instead and it's logged like this:

```
2015-03-28 18:56:11 ::1 GET /trabajos/3ba2a9e4/some-cool-tile - 2934 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.60+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 4
2015-03-28 18:56:15 ::1 GET /trabajos/3ba2a9e4/some-cool-title - 2934 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.60+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 2
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I had the same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396636/url-rewrite-in-iis-get-404) I changed the url pattern and removed the slash at the begening of the path.

this is rule that works:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite frienly url to snapshot" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="trabajos\/([\w-]+)\/([\w-|\-]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="snapshots/{R:1}.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 10):

I have the same issue, I got 404 error after setting URL rewrite rules in IIS.
Finally I found that I need to open the Reverse Proxy by click following item.

[image]

Comment: worked for me because it prompted me to install dependency modules which weren't already installed. after installing them it worked

Comment: Although I had installed Application Request Routing (ARR) it was not enabled until I tried this and a window prompted me to turn it on...

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you, that was it! Rewrite module on IIS 10 with ASP.NET Core 3.1 App