# URL Rewrite Module Not Working and Throws 404 on Localhost

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10

I have installed the URL Rewrite Module 2.1 on my computer and verified it's installed and enabled by looking at the available modules through IIS and I see "RewriteModule" (rewrite.dll). I'm trying to test out my angular app with a .net 6 web api backend locally through IIS to mimic a deployment. It seems as though the rewrite rules aren't working on my computer. When I deployed this same app with these same rules/configs to a production server with DNS set up and everything, it works and rewrites the paths. Using postman, I can hit my API directly locally through the port specified in the rewrite rule (ie. http://localhost:5004/api/user/test) but it seems as though the angular side (ttp://localhost/api/user/test) isn't able to, due to something going on.

The error I'm receiving from the UI is a 404 when trying to access the API:
[image]

Here is my web.config on the angular side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ApiProxyRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="api/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5004/api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? I also deployed this to an EC2 instance and accessed the UI through the instance's external IP address, but I received same results.

I also tried a simple rule like this one and disabling all the other rules, but I still receive a 404 error

```
        <rule name="ApiProxyRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="api/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://google.com/" />
        </rule>
```

If I change that rewrite rule to a redirect rule, it works and redirects to google.

Is there a known issue or something with URL Rewrite Module 2.1 by chance or have I been looking at this for a long time and missing something simple?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewrite in IIS 8.5 is not working I'm getting 404 instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321411/url-rewrite-in-iis-8-5-is-not-working-im-getting-404-instead)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of searching stackoverflow, asking AI, asking friends, I finally came across a post on stackoverflow that I followed and resolved the issue. Although I had installed Application Request Routing, it wasn't enabled for some reason. So if you run into this issue, check for that and ensure it's enabled (I'm not sure how to check if it's enabled or not though). The way I enabled it was following this answer, clicking "yes" to enable it, and then just closing out of the prompt.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46170177/14034867

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).